# How to iterate over boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<String>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector, stl

as the title is pretty explanatory, how is the best way to iterate over a `boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<string>>` variable?

Say that I have a structure:

```
struct foobar{
    enum typeOfVariant {intVariant, StringVariant}
    boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<String>> variable;
    }
```

That i receive at a certain point with the guarantee that the enum is corelated with the type from the variant.

To achieve maybe something like:

```
boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<string>> var;

for (auto t in var)
{
//do something
}
```

^this might be the ideal way.

Or to force conversion to a `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<string>`, based on the enum type?

Comment: What is wrong with `std::visit`?

Comment: @Yakk It's not in boost? Boost's version (named `apply_visitor`) also requires a `result_type` typedef unless you are C++14, according to the documentation.

Comment: **−1** The code presented is **not the real code**, e.g. lack of semicolon.  Also "the enum is corelated with the type from the variant." is meaningless: a  type cannot be correlated with a dynamic value. Stripped of all the misleading stuff the question is simply how to access what a `boost::variant` holds, and the **documentation** shows that.'

Answer (score 1):

In C++14:

```
apply_visitor( var, [&](auto&& var){
  for( auto&& t : var ) {
    // code goes here
  }
});
```

There is no need for the `enum`.  Variants know what type they have within themselves.

A `variant` is a union and an index into the correct type in the union.  that index is basically your `enum`.

We can do it externally with an `if` block and two versions each of which assumes the content is one type or another, or similar, but that adds bulk, and rarely adds value.

Most nominally C++11 compilers can handle the above.  Without it you have to either write a function object class manually that replicates it, or you could use the "conditional cast"s and write the loop twice, one for each type.

What can I say, C++14 solved problems.